# Custom JPanel with Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm creating a custom JPanel component and I want to show a background image in design time. My problem is: How to load an image file from the current project?

Answer:
I didn´t know but JLabel works well with images from the current project.
So I will use JLabel for now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: To the future... Try to post a question in such a way, that other people can benefit from it. You'd better don't edit your question the way you did, but post it as an answer with a proper description of your solution. Read the [FAQ].

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run into a bit of trouble with this.

If you intend to package your program as a runnable JAR file, as I do, I would recommend the following code. It requires that all of your images be located in the root of your project in a folder called "media"

```
imgURL = getClass().getResource("/media/Image_to_be_loaded.jpg");
if (imgURL != null) {
    image = new ImageIcon(imgURL, "");
    imageLabel = new JLabel(baeLogo);
} else {
    imageLabel = new JLabel("No icon found");
}
```

However, i have noticed that this code ONLY works when run from the JAR file. When i run directly from eclipse it consistently shows "No icon found"

Comment: You could try "media/Image_to_be_loaded.jpg", without the "/".  The path rules are different with/without it.

Comment: No difference. Thank you though.

Comment: `getClass()` actually calls a method on the class loader.  I guess Eclipse runs some custom class loader which doesn't know where the root of the package is.

Answer (score 0):

To load image you can use this method:

```
ImageIcon loadImageIcon(String name) {
    URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Where parameter `name` has the following constrains:

- If the name begins with a `/`, then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the `/`.
- Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form: `modified_package_name/name`, 
  where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with `/` substituted for `.`.

See [description of getResource(String name) method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

For example, if you place this method in `MyPanel.java` file and you have the following packages structure

```
swing/
  | - panel/
  |      | - MyPanel.java
  | - resources/
         | - my_image.jpg
```

than the `name` parameter maybe

either `../resources/my_image.jpg`, or `/swing/panel/resources/my_image.jpg`,

but neither `swing/panel/resources/my_image.jpg`, nor `/resources/my_image.jpg`.

### Update:

Here is the working example. In the NetBeans UI Designer you can do analog.

```
package swing.panel;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private Image img;

    public ImagePanel(String img) {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
    }

    public ImagePanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    private static ImageIcon loadImageIcon(String path) {
        URL imgURL = ImagePanel.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                ImagePanel panel =
                        new ImagePanel(loadImageIcon("../resources/image.png").getImage());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They key to getting something to show up in the GUI designer is that it will be there when the Form's default constructor is called.  If you can access the image as a resource (as others have suggested) then it will be available in the build/classes hierarchy that Netbeans uses when trying to run your class to make the Form preview in the designer.  Get this image loaded inside the default, no-argument constructor of the Form, and it should show up in the designer.